# Angular 5: Passing dynamic class name to "select" attribute of ng-content

Tags: angular5

I'm following [THIS](https://dzone.com/articles/simplifying-content-projection-in-angular) tutorial article to test how Angular Projection works. In this article I came across `select` attribute of `ng-content`, to which we can pass `class name` or `attribute` to select and target a particular `ng-content`.

Eg:

```
@Component({
  selector: 'greet',
  template: `
    <ng-content select=".headerText"></ng-content>
    <ng-content select="btnp"></ng-content>
  `


<greet>
  <h1 class="headerText">Hello</h1>
</greet>
<greet>
  <button btnp>Click Here</button>
</greet>
```

The above example works fine. But, now what I want is to dynamically pass a class name to select like:

```
<ng-content select=".headerText{{some_id}}"></ng-content>
```

But, when I attempt this, I get error:

> Can't bind to 'select' since it isn't a known property of
>   'ng-content'.

How can I achieve this?